# What are patches in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to draw a circle in Python. However, the outline of the circle is not plotting. I have tried to change the linestyle, but an error is coming up.

Comment: Which library are you using? (Matplotlib?) What’s the error? How are you attempting to make this change?

Comment: _"The error is quite lengthy but..."_ That's fine, we've got plenty of space. Let's see it.

Comment: Okay I think the only way is for me to post the code and then the error:

Comment: I have posted the code. I am very new to programming so I can only apologise if it's a mess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inconsistency in line styles is in the process of being sorted out (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3772 ).

A lightning summary of mpl architecture: `Figure`s have 1 or more `Axes` which have many `Artist`s (subtle detail, `Axes` and `Figure` are actually sub-classes of `Artist` and `Figure` objects can have other `Artist`s than just `Axes`).  `Figure` objects also have a `Canvas` objects (of which there are many implementations for outputting to different formats (ex png, tiff, svg, pdf, eps, ...).  When you draw the `Figure` there is some internal plumbing and each of the `Artist` objects are recursively drawn to the `Canvas`.

Most of the `plt` commands create an `Artist` and then add it to your current `Axes` (it `pyplot` has enough internal state to know what you current `Axes` is and create one if needed).  However, `Circle` just creates and return a `Patch` object (which is a type of `Artist`).  It is some what odd that `Circle` is directly exposed via the `pyplot` interface.

For this to work you will need to do something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# note use Circle directly from patches
circ = mpatches.Circle((1, 0), 5, linestyle='solid', edgecolor='b', facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(circ)

ax.set_xlim(-10, 10)
ax.set_ylim(-10, 10)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

Please follow PEP8, you will thank your self later.

Answer (score 3):

See the list of valid kwargs on the [Circle documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle) – `linestyle` can be one of `solid`, `dashed`, `dashdot`, or `dotted`.

```
circ = plt.Circle((x,y), R, linestyle='dashed', edgecolor='b', facecolor='none')
```

Comment: I have just tried that, but there is still no line showing

Comment: @StormHayward: Does it show up if you set a `facecolor`? What are the values of `x`, `y`, and `R`?

Comment: No it doesn't. x=71.42, y=0, R=118.5

Comment: I have read another code and they had added: ax.add_patch(circ) and it works. However, I don't actually understand why it works and what patches are.

Comment: @StormHayward: A patch is an object you add to the plot. `plt.Circle` is just a constructor for the patch and doesn’t add anything by itself.

Comment: So the patch is what draws the line?